# Singleton Conflicts and Order in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop, actionscript, singleton

If multiple instances of a singleton are trying to update the same property simultaneously, will there be any conflicts? How does AS3 handle the order?

Flash is currently single-threaded.. will the write order be an issue when it becomes multi-threaded?

Apologies for the awkward wording - I'm new to OOP and design patterns, and still grasping the basic. 'Scuse the newbieness...

Comment: By definition, a singleton has only one instance at a time...Do you mean two unrelated objects are trying to access the singleton at the same time?

Comment: why would you have multiple instances of a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)? Do you mean a [multiton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern)?

Comment: the question makes no sense, a singleton has only one instance...

Comment: i though he mean STATIC VARIABLE?

Comment: @Ocelot20 @zzzzBov @mindnoise I think he actually meant more than one reference to a singleton - it just wasn't worded correctly.

Comment: Situation is impossible as flash does not support multithreading there is absolutely no way possible to have two instances or two objects being updated or accessed simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't worded very well - there are a lot of issues here, but I think I understand what you're saying.

It's best to start with the definition of a Singleton - a Singleton is a class that only allows one object instance to be made. As such, you cannot have multiple singletons. You were probably referring to *multiple references* to a Singleton object, though, which does make sense.

As for your question - you likely won't run into two simultaneous updates, as Flash runs in a single thread and is sequential. Thus, even though AS3 allows for asynchronous events, only one thing really ever happens at one time.

As such, there won't be a conflict - the Singleton property will reflect whatever touched it last, even if the updates were a millisecond apart.

Hope this made sense.

Comment: @ina Possibly? Honestly, I don't know. Many languages that use more than one thread introduce the concept of "locking" a mutable object that spans more than one thread while a single thread is using it. I'm guessing that Actionscript would have to implement something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Flash does not support multithreading, so such situation cannot happen.

Comment: i though the question mean static variable. agree with this, if 2 object accessing one resource there will be no problem, because action script is VERY THREAD SAFE.

Comment: good call this is a ridiculous question regardless of how it is interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

How can they update it at the same time? At any given point, only one part of the program is running... Unless I'm missing something.